# Accessing cells of the row when a <td> is clicked

Tags: jquery

My requirement is to access the information in the cells of the row being clicked. A typical row looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>2015-01-01</td>
  <td>First Name</td>
  <td>Last Name</td>
  <td>2.3</td>
  <td><a href=#><img src="edit.png" class="edit"></a></td>  
</tr>
```

So you see that I need to access each cell's contents when the image is clicked.

Here's what I've tried but it's not working out:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var cells = row.children();

        console.log($(':nth-child(1)', cells).val());
    });
```

This gives me blank output.

To my frustration, I can see that `cells` is an array, and that `cells[0]` contains `<td>2015-01-01</td>` but how I extract it? Earlier I tried `cells[0].val()` but got an error saying that `undefined is not a function`. I've tried even `console.log($(':nth-child(1)', row).val());` but it gives me blank data.

Somebody please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `children` and then the `:nth-child`

```
console.log($(':nth-child(1)', row).text());
```

When you say `$(':nth-child(1)', cells)`(here `cells` are already the `td` elements) so you are trying to find the first child of the `td` elements which does not exists for the first 4 elements so it will return the `a` element in the last `td` on which you are calling the `.val()` which is not valid in your case since it is applicable only for input fields, so use `.text()` or `.html()`

Also use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of chained [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  console.log($(':nth-child(1)', row).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2015-01-01</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
    <td>
      <a href=#>
        <img src="//placehold.it/32X16&text=edit" class="edit" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: td elements do not have value. `.val()` will fail in all the circumstances.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear and to-the-point answer! Could you please elaborate why `closest()` worked here but using `var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent();` didn't?

Comment: using .parent() also should work... but using .closest() is easier

Answer (score 1):

`td` elements do not have value. You need to use .`.html()` or `.text()` instead of `.val()`

```
console.log($(cells).first().text());
```

You can also narrow down the code to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

Comment: `$(cells).first()` worked perfectly! But how do I access the remaining ones using this method? I can't seem to find any `second()`, `third()`, etc.

Comment: for accesing second element use `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text())` for third `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text())` and so on

Comment: Well, that takes us back to the accepted answer. Thanks a lot, anyway! :)